# Why does the following Ember.js code not update the given list?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, computed-observable

I've been trying some things with ember and my latest test was to update a list based on external event. I have been given some other solutions but the one I came up with (which does not work - for reasons unknown to me) is:

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ebeyab/1/edit)

If anyone could tell me why this is not working It would be great.

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scoping issue, fixed at link:

http://jsbin.com/izunik/1/edit

You were referring to "this" inside of set interval which is not the same as "this" in the view.

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake, not used to javascript. Thanks. By The way, why should I use "didInsertElement" instea of "init"?

Comment: You want to insure the view is in the DOM before adding children. Although I don't think you would get an error in this simple example I try to avoid init when possible.

Comment: Sounds good, but are there never situations when its rerenderd or something? (I can solve this with a bool - but still)

Comment: A view goes through several states depending on if bound content is changing or other factors. In your case you are changing the bound content and not the view directly so there shouldn't be an error.